# Wifi wont turn on, no matter what I do

Tags: wifi, lumia-640-xl

I have a Microsoft Lumia 640XL, and I am unable to turn on/off my WiFi. The Settings menu is showing that it's turned on, but when I click on the WiFi option it shows as off. I am unable to turn it on and it's not connecting it to any WiFi available nearby and not searching any as well.

I have done a soft reset, a hard reset and install even new OS and still is not working. What can I do?

Comment: whenever i try to turn it on it says, Try again i a little while. If the problem continues, restart your phone and try again. I have done that so many times and still nothing.

Comment: Just to get clarification, you said when its showing that its on, when you click on it, it shows that its off. You might actually be toggling the switch because when you click on it when its in one state, it switches to the other (in Windows 10 Mobile), contrary to what it used to do in Windows Phone 8.1...!! Long pressing, however, opens the full settings